# Calling pandas from within class

Tags: python-2.7

My code goes like this:

```
import pandas as pd

class some_class():

    def __init__(self,date):   
        self.start = pd.to_datetime(date)
        print self.start


day = '2017-07-11'
some_class(day)
```

everything works fine. But when I saved  >some_class<  as 'mod.py'
and tried:

```
import pandas as pd
from mod import *

day = '2017-07-11'
some_class(day)
```

then I get error: *global name 'pd' is not defined*.
Why is that? And how can I fix it?
(I tried different possible solutions and none seems to be working.)

Comment: `some_functions` isn't a class, it's a function, so perhaps start by fixing that?

Comment: Sorry I have functions and classes in 'mod'. I will correct that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, no answer so far. I needed it badly (or close to badly) and used this workaround:
just imported pandas to my mod.py

class some_class():

```
def __init__(self, date):
    import pandas as pd
    self.start = pd.to_datetime(date)
    print self.start
```

Not ideal but works.

So I suspect there exists two different namespaces. If so, this solution unnecessary load pandas to mod.py's namespace. I will post more when I look more into this problem .